# In-App Purchases Boolean always false

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I have an app LIVE in PRODUCTION and when I buy something nothing happens! and then when I click it a second time it calls the listener and **result.isSuccess** is always false! Please help.

I can't seem to find the solution. My onActivityResult is setup correctly. Google Play says purchase complete. Everything works accordingly but my listener never executes the code. I am sure this is a simple fix and I am just overlooking it.

Check if result.isSuccessful() -> evaluate code. The first time you purchase it... Nothing happens. The else statement isn't called. The Success Statement isn't called. The second time you push the button to buy the item it calls the else statement in the corresponding listener. I so badly would like an error message, but no error is being thrown. Hm...

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store, container, false);

        removeAdsOnly = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.store_ads_btn);
        removeAdsOnly.setOnClickListener(this);

        mHelper = new IabHelper(getContext(), base64EncodedPublicKey);

        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if(!result.isSuccess()){
                    Log.d(AppUtils.APP_NAME, "In-App Billing setup failed: " + result);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed to setup in-app billing.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Log.d(AppUtils.APP_NAME, "In-App Billing setup is OK");
                }
            }
        });


        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Store.this.getActivity().getBaseContext());
        boolean adsPurchased = prefs.getBoolean("purchasedAds", false);

        if(adsPurchased){
            removeAdsOnly.setClickable(false);
            removeAdsOnly.setAlpha(0.5f);
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        //TODO: Uncomment StartAppSDK.inAppPurchaseMade Upon Release

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Store.this.getActivity().getBaseContext());
        boolean adsPurchased = prefs.getBoolean("purchasedAds", false);

        if(id == removeAdsOnly.getId()){
            if(!adsPurchased){
                mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(Store.this.getActivity(), ADSPACK_SKU, 10001, adsPuchaseListener);
                //StartAppSDK.inAppPurchaseMade(getContext(), 0.99);

                    if(developerStore){
                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                        edit.putBoolean("purchasedAds", Boolean.TRUE);
                        edit.commit();
                    }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Looks like you have already purchased this item.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(AppUtils.APP_NAME, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);

        // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
            // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
            // billing...
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
        else {
            Log.d(AppUtils.APP_NAME, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
        }
    }

    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener adsPuchaseListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
            if(result.isSuccess()){
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Store.this.getActivity().getBaseContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                edit.putBoolean("purchasedAds", Boolean.TRUE);
                edit.commit();

                removeAdsOnly.setClickable(false);
                removeAdsOnly.setAlpha(0.5f);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed to purchase Ad Removal.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: This is a giant code dump. You need to start debugging it using the standard techniques.

Comment: @chrylis unfortunately all the code I placed in the application I believe is relevant to solving the issue. If you could please tell me what you call "standard debugging techniques" that would be great. I simply don't see how I can debug something where the value is simply zero and one - true or false.

Comment: You don't even say *which* `result.isSuccess()`. Perhaps start by inspecting the accompanying error message, which is being logged.

Comment: @chrylis I have three listeners. All there follow the same format. Check if result.isSuccessful() -> evaluate code. The first time you purchase it... Nothing happens. The else statement isn't called. The Success Statement isn't called. The second time you push the button to buy the item it calls the else statement in the corresponding listener. I so badly would like an error message, but no error is being thrown. Hm... If you could please look into the issue. I know I don't have much to show, just some code. I need this issue fixed soon and this site is my life-line.

Comment: To follow up on @chrylis ' s question - all of the buttons are necessary to recreate the problem? All of the listeners, attached to each of the buttons? Even the buttons that you're not pressing in your description of the problem? All of the calls to `setClickable` and `setAlpha`?

Comment: @BobGilmore Yes. I will revise my code to only one button and one listener. It persists with all though